# Force kill subprocess with a very big shell script

Tags: node.js, unix, subprocess

I have a big ffmpeg shell script of 80.000 chars and another smaller one.

I'm executing it with execa and i get a PID.
`` execa(`chmod +x command.sh; chmod +x command2.sh; ./command.sh & ./command2.sh`, {shell: true, detached: true} ``

After i leave a tab i'm executing `exec(kill -9 ${pid})` on that subprocess. And it takes like 3-4 minutes to kill it. How can i optimize this? Can i kill it instantly? In that 3-4 min time that it tries to close, it takes a lot of CPU power.

#### Followup infomration

So i have 2 shell scripts.

One for audio stream and one for video stream.

I'm using & to execute them at the same time, because i need both audio and video at the same time when playing a video.

`audioStream.sh` is just a ffmpeg command that outputs hls audio chunks.

`videoStream.sh` contains 400 ImageMagick commands that convert images with border and 85 ffmpeg commands that outputs video hls chunks that go into the m3u8 master playlist which goes into the video player. The commands are delimited with ';'.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Without knowing what the scripts do it is difficult to guess what's happening. Is it intentional that you run `./command.sh` in background and `./command2.sh` in foreground? Please [edit] your question to provide more details. Normally you should not use `kill -9` but `kill ${pid}` to give the process a chance to clean up before terminating. `kill -9` should only be used as a last resort if the program cannot be stopped by other means. It is a bit unclear what happens to your scripts when you kill the shell process this way.

Comment: @Bodo thank you for your answer. 

So i have 2 shell scripts. One for audio stream and one for video stream.
I'm using & to execute them at the same time, because i need both audio and video at the same time when playing a video.

audioStream.sh is just a ffmpeg command that outputs hls audio chunks.

videoStream.sh contains 400 ImageMagick commands that convert images with border and 85 ffmpeg commands that outputs video hls chunks that go into the m3u8 master playlist which goes into the video player. The commands are delimited with ';'.

Comment: Please don't use comments to add information. **[Edit] your question instead.** Your concept looks strange. If you have one process for audio and one for video running independently you won't have any synchronization. I doubt that this will work for playing the resulting video at the same time. What happens if the audio data is ready for a certain point of playing time and the video data is not. I suggest to show example scripts with a reduced number of commands. Instead of 400 + 85 commands show e.g. 5 each. Please add more details about your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to start debugging your code as a simple `bash` script.

#### bash-script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

chmod +x command.sh; 
chmod +x command2.sh; 
./command.sh & 
./command2.sh
```

Once your script is running try to kill your command with `pkill` command.

Something like:

```
 pkill -9 -f "command.sh"
```

See how long it takes to kill it.

If it takes too long. Run ./command.sh from the command line and try to kill it again with `pkill` command as above. If it is still take long.

The problem is in `command.sh` script handling SIGKILL signals from the operating system and you should study the `command.sh` command line arguments enabling it to trap SIGKILL signals.

Comment: thank you for your answer.

I've tried the solution with trap SIGKILL signals.
So i have `init.sh` that contains 

``#!/bin/bash
trap 'print TERM received;exit' 15
chmod +x command.sh; 
chmod +x command2.sh; 
./command.sh & 
./command2.sh ``

Then if i pkill trap catches the signal and exits, but i get exitCode 1 and failed: true, and the scripts are getting killed again after 1-2, no change.